# What Is Result Of calc() In CSS

Tags: css, css-calc

We have now started using `calc()` in css, for setting widths on a result of calculation. 
For example:

```
<div id='parent'>
<div id='calcWidth'></div>
</div>


   #parent{
           width:100px;
           }
   #calcWidth{
            width:calc(100% - 3px);
            height:100px;
            background:red;
           }
```

I know how `calc()` works, but I just want to know what is returned in css, in the place of `calc(100% - 3px);` in the example given above.

**Whats my confusion?**

- In the above example `width:calc(100% - 3px);`
- say the `100%` width is actually `100px`, which will be determined at runtime by css.
- So the calculated width will be `100px-3px=97px` 97px and if you convert it to `%` `97%` right?

But now, there are  two possibilities

- `97px` is returned, which is set as a width.
- `97%` is returned, which is set as a width.

**My Question is:**

> In both cases now the width shall be set to `97px`, but what is
>   returned as a result of `width:calc(100% - 3px);`, `97px` OR `97%` ?

you can also see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8yspnuuw/1/

**EDIT: please read**

See friends: Take a simple example:

```
 <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
    </div>

.parent{
width:200px;
}
 .child{
  width:20%
  }
```

> I know the width of child will become 160 px when it is rendered.
>   okay! but thats not what is set in css right? css sets it in %, it is
>   just rendered in pixels.

So similarly, using calc, ***does it return `%` or `pixel`***

Or to explain my question, read [BoltClocks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28716226/3556874), what is the **computed value**, (and not the used value, i know that is in pixels)

Comment: You can use FireBug to see the computed style, or run getComputedStyle by yourself using console: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle and just test it :)

Comment: Given that the end-result is always rendered in pixels, why does the specific format of `calc()`'s return value matter? I'm guessing it's always going to be in pixels, since that's what every computed value of lengths are ultimately assigned/rendered-in, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#calc-computed-value) does not define very strictly what the computed value of a `calc()` expression is, however it does say that percentages are never calculated as part of the computed value. How exactly this value is *represented* is left as an implementation detail.

If you see a pixel length instead of a percentage, then that length is the used value, not the computed value, because the pixel value can only be determined *after* calculating any percentages and laying out elements.

Note that `getComputedStyle()` may return results that are inconsistent with the CSS definition of "computed value". This is one of many unfortunate consequences of browsers doing their own thing back in the 90s.

Comment: so does that mean pixels is what is set by calc?

Comment: @Naeem Shaikh: The pixel value is used in rendering (hence "used value").

Answer (score 5):

The rendered widths are in pixels.[image: from your example]

Comment: i know it is rendered in pixels:  you read my question **In both cases now the width shall be set to 97px**, but what is returned as a result of cals is my question

Comment: It returns a function, the value is rendered into pixels. Why is this important?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the pixels size of the calcWidth div is, the value 3 is reduced from it..for example if the width of parent is 200 the calcWidth div's width will be 197px. so it is px and not %

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshman/01mnmcbm/)

```
 document.getElementById('calcWidth').offsetWidth;
```

[image: image style in pixel jsdemo]

Comment: i dont really agree this is wrong iguess.. try to set property where, width should only be in px, for example box-shadow

Comment: I understand what you are saying.. but my question is little difficult to grasp i guess.. please read my edited question

Comment: @NaeemShaikh the calc() uses % however the computed style in chrome shows that the rendered value is in pixels..so i guess that's the answer as BoltClock mentioned in his answer..cheers

Comment: Lucke please see my answer, iguess you can understand, what i m thinking right now

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not support dynamic values (bedides simple percentage values like `width: 100%;`). That means the `100%` within `calc()` are converted one time initially to `px` and not continiously.

That already answers your question. The `%`-value gets converted into `px` end you end up with `97px`. You can confirm that with `window.getComputedStyle()` or by taking a screenshot and measure it.

Answer (score 0):

calc() does not have a computed value; it occurs at time of render -- that is why you can mix units.