# Getting result of CSS calc to set custom properties

Tags: css, css-calc, css-variables

I'm testing a CSS framework for specifying numbers via micro-classes. For instance, something like `<div class="fifty percent wide">` might translate into `width: 50%`. The implementation uses CSS variables (custom properties).

Consider the following CSS:

```
.fifty   { --number: 50; }
.percent { --percent: calc(1% * var(--number)); }
.wide    { width: var(--percent); }
```

That's all fine and works great. The issue is that I want to write a test suite, which would verify that `fifty percent` results in a value for the custom property `--percent` of `50%`. Unfortunately, if I use `getComputedStyle` to examine the value of `--percent`, I see the entire (unresolved, uncomputed) "calc" string. If I examine the value of `width`, I get the already-resolved value such as "512px".

Is there some way to obtain and validate programatically the resolved, calculated values of custom CSS properties? Or an API to force the evaluation of "calc" expressions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715872/what-is-result-of-calc-in-css although that has nothing to do with how custom properties are computed, it offers a bit of insight as to how underspecced calc() is in this area.

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo error in `.percent` class:

```
.percent { --percent: calc(1% * var(--number); }
//                                          ^    you have to close Brackets of Calc()
.percent { --percent: calc(1% * var(--number)); }
```

I suggest to do a simple test by getting the width of element and its parent in px, something like:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("test");
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var elem_width = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("width");

alert("50% of 200px parent width = " + elem_width);
```

```css
#parent{
  background-color:black;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.fifty   { --number: 50; }
.percent { --percent: calc(1% * var(--number)); }
.wide    {
   width: var(--percent);
   height: 100px;
   background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="test" class="fifty percent wide">
    </div>
</div>
```

<sub>**NOTE:** Attributes or CSS styles it does not understand from the code to the DOM. That is by design. Javascript only has access to the DOM, not the code. So no, there is no way to access a property from javascript that the browser itself does not support.</sub>

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for reply, but do you agree with me about my answer?

Comment: Yes, it works fine for percentages, but I would have to develop similar workarounds for combinations of classes designed to produce various kinds of lengths, pure integers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using the [CSS Properties and Values API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Properties_and_Values_API) (Houdini).
Once `--percent` is properly registered as a percentage, `getPropertyValue()` should yield the expected result.

For example:

```
@property --percent {
 syntax: '<percentage>';
 inherits: false;
 initial-value: 50%;
}
```

February 2023: [the support is still limited](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property) (Firefox doesn't support it).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to calculate the percentage yourself by getting the width from the element and it's parent (in pixels). Then simply divide `parentWidth` by `elementWidth` to calculate the percentage.

Also, maybe you could test the CSS manually. If everything works as expected, you wouldn't need any more test cases. It's not like this breaks over night, right?