# How to use bootstrap container's width as variable in calc

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

```
calc((100% - 1240px) / 2)
```

In this code I want to use width of container as variable instead of writing 1240px, so it is changing as width of screen is changing. I'm using bootstrap with sass. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: there's a chance you are trying to achieve something that could be solved differently.. anyway what if "1240px" was a css custom variable and you used it on both the container width and that calc() processing?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I'm doing an animation, and I need to place logo on the same spot at every device screen, what do you mean by custom variable

Comment: I meant something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603683/getting-result-of-css-calc-to-set-custom-properties where you define a custom property (that fixed width) and use it both on the css rule to style the .container and the rule to style the elements that need that calc formula.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what I was trying to explain in my comments above.

By the way there are surely better solutions for your problem.

```css
:root {
  --container-width: 200px;
}

.container{
  width: var(--container-width);
  border: solid 1px red;
}

#target{
  border: solid 1px green;
  width: calc((100% - var(--container-width)) / 2)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Container</div>
<br>
<div id="target">Target</div>
```